# Modifying include paths in custom C++ Bazel rule

Tags: c++, include, bazel, bazel-rules

I'm building some custom C++ Bazel rules, and I need to add support for modifying the include paths of the C++ headers, the same way `cc_library` headers can be modified with [`strip_include_prefix`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.strip_include_prefix).

My custom rule is implemented using `ctx.actions.run` like this:

```
custom_cc_library = rule(
  _impl,
  attrs = {
    ...
    "hdrs": attr.label_list(allow_files = [".h"]),
    "strip_include_prefix": attr.string(),
    ...
  },
)
```

Then within `_impl` I call the following function to rewrite `hdrs`:

```
def _strip_prefix(ctx, hdrs, prefix):
    stripped = []
    for hdr in hdrs:
        stripped = hdr
        if file.path.startswith(strip_prefix):
            stripped_file = ctx.actions.declare_file(file.path[len(strip_prefix):])
            ctx.actions.run_shell(
                command = "mkdir -p {dest} && cp {src} {dest};".format(src=hdr.path, dest=stripped.path),
                inputs = [hdr],
                outputs = [stripped],
            )
        stripped.append(stripped_file)
    return stripped
```

This doesn't work because Bazel won't copy files outside of their package directory, and besides it feels like the totally wrong approach to implementing this.

What is the best way to modify C++ header directories for dependencies to achieve the same functionality as `cc_library`'s parameter `strip_include_prefix`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the [cc_library rule](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/f0c7ff45a04a8bb03517ca692ec8d530175f7232/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/rules/cpp/BazelCcLibraryRule.java#L27), and its [stripIncludePrefix implementation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/137b759c8f6d37d7512d621571aa9446d5c1ec4d/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CcCompilationHelper.java#L833) are in Bazel's Java code.

Comment: @Laurenz yup I know, it's a pity. But I'm hoping to find a way to implement similar functionality within Starlark.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the header layout you want in a directory within your package, and then add that to the include path via [`create_compilation_outputs.includes`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/cc_common.html#create_compilation_context). That's basically what the cc_library implementation boils down to.

The cc_library implementation [names it `_virtual_includes`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/137b759c8f6d37d7512d621571aa9446d5c1ec4d/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CcCompilationHelper.java#L891), and creates it using `getUniqueDirectoryArtifact` which is a helper in the Java code to create it ["in a directory that is unique to the rule"](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/ec1cdc953a01b0ebfac9e10665dae6d82e5e01fd/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/analysis/actions/ActionConstructionContext.java#L110). I use something like `"_%s_virtual_includes" % ctx.label.name` to get similar functionality from Starlark, and give a hint that it's a private implementation detail which other rules should avoid relying on.